# How to handle error in Lightgbm with custom loss?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, lightgbm

I'm getting an error when trying to use my own custom loss function in lightgbm.cv whereas the same function works fine within the sklearn API of lightgbm.

My loss function:

```
def custom_squared_log(y_true, y_pred):
    y_pred[y_pred < -1] = -1 + 1e-6
    grad = (np.log1p(y_pred) - np.log1p(y_true)) / (y_pred + 1)
    hess = ((-np.log1p(y_pred) + np.log1p(y_true) + 1) / np.power(y_pred + 1, 2))
    return grad, hess

def rmsle(y_true, y_pred):
    y_pred[y_pred < -1] = -1 + 1e-6
    squared_logs = np.power(np.log1p(y_true) - np.log1p(y_pred), 2)
    return 'rmsle', float(np.sqrt(np.sum(squared_logs) / len(y_true))), False
```

Then I try to use LGB Regressor in the following way:

```
lgb_base = lgb.LGBMRegressor(
    learning_rate = 0.1,
    n_estimators = 10000,
    max_depth = -1,
    min_data_in_leaf = 10,
    num_leaves = 63,
    subsample = 0.8,
    colsample_bytree = 1.0,
    objective = 'regression',
    nthread = -1,
    seed = 27,
    reg_alpha = 1e-2
)

lgb_param = lgb_base.get_params()
lgbtrain = lgb.Dataset(X.values, label=y.values)

cvresult = lgb.cv(lgb_base.get_params(), lgbtrain, num_boost_round=lgb_base.get_params()['n_estimators'], nfold=4,
                  early_stopping_rounds=50, stratified=False,
                  fobj = custom_squared_log, feval = rmsle)
```

And then I'm getting the error:

[TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'float' and 'Dataset'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DKPnf.png)

If I'm using sklearn API the same loss works fine.

Comment: I think you should update your post to include all necessary implementations so that anyone who may help you can reproduce the error. Also, normally the error message shows the part of the code that produces the error; you should also include that too.

Comment: Sorry, I'm newby here. I have no permission to add picture right in a post, however error screenshot was added automatically by link (I've just tried to attach screenshot in the post and it's automatically turned to link). Thank you!

Comment: Plese read the description of the [tag:ml] tag.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. Edited.

Comment: I think the error message quite clearly points out that y_pred is of type 'Dataset', so maybe you can put in a print or log call there to see what is the type and value of y_pred at the point of error? Using that I think maybe you can backtrack to the source of the problem.

Comment: I guess, you get a pandas dataframe (which can handle +) if you work with the Sklearn API and a dataset, if you work with the native API. So in case of the native API you probably only have to "unwrap" your Dataset object.

Answer (score 1):

One of the arguments passed to your function has type Dataset. So, you should use, for example, y_true.get_label() instead of y_true.

Not sure if the argument's order is right in your function. I mean def custom_squared_log(y_true, y_pred): -> def custom_squared_log(y_pred, y_true).